# How to change the text of a header of a column of a ListView in WPF from C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, header

I found out I can do

```
((GridView)myListView.View).Columns[i].Width = x;
```

to change the width. But how to Change the Header text? I can't find anything like

```
((GridView)myListView.View).Columns[i].Content = "Hello World";
```

Comment: dataGridView1.Columns[i].Header = "Hello World";?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to change the header property;

```
((GridView)myListView.View).Columns[i].Header = "Hello World";
```